# Socket Read/Write error

Tags: c, sockets, stream, segmentation-fault

would install valgrind to tell me what the problem is, but unfortunately can't any new programs on this computer... Could anyone tell me if there's an obvious problem with this "echo" program? Doing this for a friend, so not sure what the layout of the client is on the other side, but I know that both reads and writes are valid socket descriptors, and I've tested that n = write(writes,"I got your message \n",20); and n = write(reads,"I got your message \n",20); both work so can confirm that it's not a case of an invalid fd. Thanks!

```
int
main( int argc, char** argv ) {


 int reads = atoi(argv[1]) ; 
 int writes = atoi(argv[3]) ; 
 int n ; 


  char buffer[MAX_LINE];
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));



  int i = 0 ; 
  while (1) {
    read(reads, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    n = write(writes,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    if (n < 0)  perror("ERROR reading from socket"); 

  }
```

Comment: Check the read() result in-case of error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems, the most pressing of which is that you're likely pushing garbage data down the the write socket by using sizeof(buffer) when writing. Lets say you read data from the reads socket and it's less than MAX_LINES. When you go to write that data, you'll be writing whatever you read plus the garbage at the end of the buffer (even though you memset at the very beginning, continual use of the same buffer without reacting to different read sizes will probably generate some garbage.

Try getting the return value from read and using it in your write. If the read return indicates an error, clean up and either exit or try again, depending on how you want your program to behave.

```
int n, size;
while (1) {
   size = read(reads, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

   if (size > 0) {
       n = write(writes, buffer, size);

       if (n != size) {
           // write error, do something
       }  
   } else {
       // Read error, do something
   }
}
```

This, of course, assumes your writes and reads are valid file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines look very suspicious:

```
int reads = atoi(argv[1]) ; 
int writes = atoi(argv[3]) ;
```

Do you really get file/socket descriptor numbers on the command line? From where?

Check the return value of your [`read(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) and [`write(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html), and then the value of [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) - they probably tell you that your file descriptors are invalid (`EBADF`).

Comment: No my file descriptors are definitely valid (doubled check by me being able to do n = write(reads,"I got your message \n",20) and receiving it on the other side

Comment: if I put a random value in reads, or writes then I do indeed get "invalid file descriptors") but my code fails silently right now

Comment: What do you mean by "silently"?

Comment: Debug it with gdb? Pretty short program, stepping through it line by line will probably show you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One point not made thus far: Although you know that the file descriptors are valid, you should include some sanity checking of the command line.

```
if (argc < 3) {
       printf("usage: foo: input output\n");
       exit(0);
}
```

Even with this sanity checking passing parameters like this on a command line can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `memset()` is not needed, provided you change the following (which you should do nevertheless).
2. `read()` has a result, telling you how much it has actually read. This you should give to `write()` in order to write only what you actually have, removing the need for zeroing.
3. `MAX_LINE` should be at least 512, if not more.

There probably are some more issues, but I think I have the most important ones.

Comment: using memset or not wouldn't have any impact on whether it succeeds or not. same for max_line being >512. Either way Still doesn't work :(

Comment: You are right. My main point is 2., which can affect much. BTW: You still didn't tell us what is really the problem...